# Lindelöf Hypothesis and the Karatsuba conjectures

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I'm aware of Shao-Ji Feng's result that Karatsuba's weaker conjecture ("conjecture 1") is true conditionally on the Lindelöf Hypothesis.

- Shao-Ji Feng, "[On Karatsuba conjecture and the Lindelöf hypothesis](https://www.impan.pl/download/pdf/aa114-3-4)" (2004)

Is the following, stronger conjecture ("conjecture 3", also due to Karatsuba), known to hold under the Lindelöf Hypothesis?

> **Karatsuba strong conjecture**. Let
>
> $$F(T,\Delta)=\max_{t\in [T,T+\Delta]} |\zeta(1/2+it)|$$
>
> where $0<\Delta\leq 1$. Then, for some constant $A>0$,
>
> $$F(T,\Delta)\geq T^{-A}$$
>
> is true for $\Delta(T)=(\log T)^{-1}$.